# Javac configuration parameter for unused include warnings?

Tags: java, ant, command-line-arguments, javac

Is there a Sun command line parameter to provide warnings (or errors) in reference to unused `import` statements?  The embedded eclipse javac compiler provides such warnings, but if the Sun / Oracle compiler has it as one of their `-Xlint:XXX` arguments, it is not well documented.

I'm looking to clean up an existing Java code base, which builds from the command line using Ant, and I would like integrate tracking and reporting of such statements into the nightly builds.

Some have suggested that imports have no effect on the compilation process, however looking at the compiler operations (with the -verbose flag) indicates that the compiler loads the imported classes unconditionally, even if they are not used in the written output.  So, removing unused imports seems to have more benefits than just code comprehension at a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), and configure the `UnusedImports` module to be used (or pick a default configuration that already uses it).

Checkstyle defines an unused import as:

1. An non-wildcard import that is not referenced in the file.
2. An import that is a duplicate of another import.
3. An import from the `java.lang` package.
4. An import from the same package as the class.
5. (Optionally) an import that is only needed to resolve a JavaDoc link.

In practice, it creates a report that `java.awt.Component` is not used (along with the line number).

```
import java.awt.Component;
class FooBar {
    ...
}
```

It does have some limitations, in the sense it can be confused by members with the same name as an import; but, this failure rarely finds it's way into practice for most developers.

From the documentation as to the limitation

```
import java.awt.Component;
class FooBar {
    private Object Component; // IMHO bad practice
    ...
}
```

Would **not** flag `Component` as unused.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you look at FindBugs instead for reporting on the cleanliness of the code as part of your nightly builds. FindBugs can detect a lot more potential problems than either the JDK Java compiler or the one in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not denying the benefit of FindBugs, but it would be nice to know how to do this from the command line.

Comment: Why do you assume that javac can report these problems? The primary job of the compiler is to compile code. The compiler will report warnings if it is convenient as part of compiling code, but will generally not going to go out of its way to hunt down situations that would result in warnings. It is simply not its job and would make for a less efficient compiler. The Eclipse compiler situation is a different. Developers using IDE expect more in the way of detection of potential problems and performance in batch compilation isn't as critical.

Comment: If a compiler isn't supposed to issue warnings, they why do they?  This is obviously an issue that is properly checked at compile time, as it would be silly to check it at run time.  As an aside, it's too bad that FindBugs is LGPLv3, that's a no-go for this situation.

Comment: I assume javac can report these problems because it already has mechanism to do so `javac -Xlint:xyz`

Comment: @Edwin: Unused imports are no problem at all, so they don't have to be checked. (Imports are thrown away when compiling, so checking at runtime is impossible, too.)

Comment: @Paulo,  You seem to forget that source code is written and maintained by people.  Unused imports clutter a person's perception of what a class is and isn't connected to.  If a class has a large number of unused imports, then the person will eventually ignore all the imports, or be misled by the imports; neither of which scenarios are desirable.

Comment: Since FindBugs operates on compiled bytecode, how could it possibly detect unused imports?

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik, the "[fact sheet](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/factSheet.html)" says it operates on bytecode and the [detected bugs page](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) does not mention anything at all about imports.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It operates on both bytecode and source. At least it requires both as an input via the project file.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik while findbugs is a good test suite, it doesn't actually ship with a source code import test.  I guess one could be written, but I found a better (already written) solution.